# Bootstrap :Go to specific tab using a button in other page

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

In here,i have 2 HTML page(a.html,b.html), I use Bootstrap Tab in a.html to show different information.

**a.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link href="http://libs.baidu.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="http://libs.baidu.com/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://libs.baidu.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">
      Home</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#ios" data-toggle="tab">iOS</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" id="myTabDrop1" class="dropdown-toggle" 
         data-toggle="dropdown">Java <b class="caret"></b>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="myTabDrop1">
         <li><a href="#jmeter" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">
            jmeter</a>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#ejb" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">
            ejb</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
   <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="home">
      <p>abc</p>
   </div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="ios">
      <p>123</p>
   </div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="jmeter">
      <p>456</p>
   </div>
   <div class="tab-pane fade" id="ejb">
      <p>789</p>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I have another page(b.html),in (b.html),it has a button,I want if i click the button, I can back to a.html and show out the specific tab(ejb) in dropdown list(Java).How can I do it?

I try Default (Gray) Button,but it is not work.

If need to change the page to php to show out the specific tab, i can change it.

**b.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>button</h2>
      <a class="btn" type="button" href="a.html">Default (Gray) Button</a>
    </div>

  <script src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: when getting back to a.html, you need the dropdown (#ejb) opened?

Comment: @Jean Gkol yes, I want to show out specific tab(ejb) in a.html when i click button in b.html

Comment: unfortunately, I'm just able to do that in php script, not full html .. even in javascript

Comment: @Jean Gkol php is ok. I can change to php.

Answer (score 1):

This is the step you need to try:

I. Add new parameter in the end of the a.php's URL (I mean, in button to be clicked in b.php) This is used to be a signal for a.php to see if it is spesific URL to handle.

For example:

`http://www.myweb.com/a.php`**?q=ejb**

So, in b.php, the whole codes will be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/bootstrap/3.3.0
/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <h2>button</h2>
      <a class="btn" type="button" href="http://www.myweb.com/a.php?q=ejb">Default (Gray) Button</a>
    </div>

  <script src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://apps.bdimg.com/libs/bootstrap/3.3.0
/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

2. This follows is for **a.php** scripting:

> ```
> <?php
> $url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
> if ($url=="http://www.myweb.com/a.php?q=ejb"){ //this is the point.
> print "<div id='myTabContent' class='tab-content'>
>   <div class='tab-pane fade' id='home'>
>   <p>abc</p>
>   </div>
>   <div class='tab-pane fade' id='ios'>
>   <p>123</p>
>   </div>
>   <div class='tab-pane fade' id='jmeter'>
>   <p>456</p>
>   </div>
>   <div class='tab-pane fade in active' id='ejb'>
>   <p>789</p>
>   </div>
>   </div>";
>   }
> else{
> print "<div id='myTabContent' class='tab-content'>
>   <div class='tab-pane fade in active' id='home'>
>   <p>abc</p>
>   </div>
>   <div class='tab-pane fade' id='ios'>
>   <p>123</p>
>   </div>
>   <div class='tab-pane fade' id='jmeter'>
>   <p>456</p>
>   </div>
>   <div class='tab-pane fade' id='ejb'>
>   <p>789</p>
>   </div>
>   </div>";
>   }
> ?>
> ```

**Note**: From the two (2) you can see that you just need to add  `in active` which tab you need to open or to visit back.

So, the whole codes for a.php will be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <link href="http://libs.baidu.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="http://libs.baidu.com/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="http://libs.baidu.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
   <li class="active"><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">
      Home</a>
   </li>
   <li><a href="#ios" data-toggle="tab">iOS</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" id="myTabDrop1" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Java <b class="caret"></b></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="myTabDrop1">
         <li><a href="#jmeter" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="tab">
            jmeter</a>
         </li>
         <li><a href="#ejb" tabindex="-1" id="test_open_menu" data-toggle="tab">
            ejb</a>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>

<?php
$url="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if ($url=="http://localhost/test/a.php?q=ejb"){
print "<div id='myTabContent' class='tab-content'>
    <div class='tab-pane fade' id='home'>
    <p>abc</p>
    </div>
    <div class='tab-pane fade' id='ios'>
    <p>123</p>
    </div>
    <div class='tab-pane fade' id='jmeter'>
    <p>456</p>
    </div>
    <div class='tab-pane fade in active' id='ejb'>
    <p>789</p>
    </div>
    </div>";
    }
else{
print "<div id='myTabContent' class='tab-content'>
    <div class='tab-pane fade in active' id='home'>
    <p>abc</p>
    </div>
    <div class='tab-pane fade' id='ios'>
    <p>123</p>
    </div>
    <div class='tab-pane fade' id='jmeter'>
    <p>456</p>
    </div>
    <div class='tab-pane fade' id='ejb'>
    <p>789</p>
    </div>
    </div>";
    }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Sorry for long answer. This is what I can say since I have no good enough in English spoken.
Really hopes this work for you and be inspired for you to modify it in javascript.

Comment: Sorry, the code is not work, the tab(ejb) cannot show out .Also all Bootstrap tab is fail to show out.

Comment: really? well, :D i found really work here. do you want me to show it in my web page? then I need 5 minutes again to do that :D

Comment: I see there's a <br> tag to avoid it show ... sorry .. I will edit it then again

Comment: sorry, I redirect it since there's no index inside it :p
try this then: http://appacyber.net/appalab/test/b.php

Comment: In firefox, if i click the button in b.php , a.php still show the Home tab.Why?

Comment: I have checked all the source and it runs as I wish and I simply don't know why it didn;t work with you with FF. what about in chrome or safari? have you tried it? I think no impacts in related to browser here. you can try also to remove the bootstrap link and change to maxcdn instead

Comment: I try all browser before, this effect can do it via javascript?

Comment: Can i do it via javascript?